# Failure building documentation

Tags: documentation

I've been trying to build documentation to no avail: Below is the log of the output i get after running `nix build -f default.nix docs.site --extra-experimental-features nix-command`

```
@nix { "action": "setPhase", "phase": "unpackPhase" }
unpacking sources
unpacking source archive /nix/store/v2rkjvsh6559c5mrix371zzf10jjf64k-openapi3-3.2.2.tar.gz
source root is openapi3-3.2.2
setting SOURCE_DATE_EPOCH to timestamp 1000000000 of file openapi3-3.2.2/test/Spec.hs
@nix { "action": "setPhase", "phase": "patchPhase" }
patching sources
@nix { "action": "setPhase", "phase": "configurePhase" }
configuring
Configure flags:
--prefix=/nix/store/54gdr97lm30cjrhybh3jhzgvyqf0gs3m-openapi3-lib-openapi3-3.2.2 lib:openapi3 --package-db=clear --package-db=/nix/store/5wc>Configuring library for openapi3-3.2.2..
@nix { "action": "setPhase", "phase": "buildPhase" }
building
Preprocessing library for openapi3-3.2.2..
Building library for openapi3-3.2.2..
[ 1 of 18] Compiling Data.OpenApi.Aeson.Compat ( src/Data/OpenApi/Aeson/Compat.hs, dist/build/Data/OpenApi/Aeson/Compat.o, dist/build/Data/O>[ 2 of 18] Compiling Data.OpenApi.Declare ( src/Data/OpenApi/Declare.hs, dist/build/Data/OpenApi/Declare.o, dist/build/Data/OpenApi/Declare.>exprType TYPE: p_akIy
exprType TYPE: p_akIy
exprType TYPE: p_akIy
exprType TYPE: p_akIy
exprType TYPE: p_akIy
exprType TYPE: p_akIy
exprType TYPE: p_akIy
exprType TYPE: p_akIy
exprType TYPE: p_akIy
exprType TYPE: p_akIy
exprType TYPE: p_akIy
exprType TYPE: p_akIy
exprType TYPE: p_akIy
exprType TYPE: p_akIy
exprType TYPE: p_akIy
exprType TYPE: p_akIy
exprType TYPE: Text
exprType TYPE: Text
[ 3 of 18] Compiling Data.OpenApi.Internal.AesonUtils ( src/Data/OpenApi/Internal/AesonUtils.hs, dist/build/Data/OpenApi/Internal/AesonUtils>[ 4 of 18] Compiling Data.OpenApi.Internal.TypeShape ( src/Data/OpenApi/Internal/TypeShape.hs, dist/build/Data/OpenApi/Internal/TypeShape.o,>[ 5 of 18] Compiling Data.OpenApi.Internal.Utils ( src/Data/OpenApi/Internal/Utils.hs, dist/build/Data/OpenApi/Internal/Utils.o, dist/build/>[ 6 of 18] Compiling Data.OpenApi.Internal ( src/Data/OpenApi/Internal.hs, dist/build/Data/OpenApi/Internal.o, dist/build/Data/OpenApi/Inter>exprType TYPE: Text
exprType TYPE: Text
exprType TYPE: Text
exprType TYPE: Text
exprType TYPE: Text
exprType TYPE: Text
exprType TYPE: Text
exprType TYPE: Text
exprType TYPE: Text
exprType TYPE: Text
exprType TYPE: Text
exprType TYPE: Text
/nix/store/cjl2qfa8h01l0qk1748ynbhwi1zv8vf6-stdenv-linux/setup: line 1400:   120 Killed                  $SETUP_HS build lib:openapi3 -j$(($>
```

Comment: What documentation are you trying to build?

Comment: I'm trying to build the `plutus-apps` documentation

Comment: Works for me. Have you correctly configured the binary cache as per docs? Note it changed last month.
You could also try entering `nix-shell` and running `build-and-serve-docs` to build and host docs.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I just tried it and got the same... ```... error: 1 dependencies of derivation '/nix/store/m1ss6ik6fh7q5il3b9lznf8kd8bjwqvf-plutus-use-cases-lib-plutus-use-cases-1.0.0.0.drv' failed to build
error: 1 dependencies of derivation '/nix/store/q1m6kkkk94rlmiqxrvbn0wcw9nqpq7vk-haddock-join.drv' failed to build
error: 1 dependencies of derivation '/nix/store/b8wj79ccfhjhx1jj58b4dmn4p27ad2qs-plutus-docs.drv' failed to build
Serving HTTP on 0.0.0.0 port 8002 (http://0.0.0.0:8002/) ... ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out the issue was a memory issue. I closed all applications running on the pc and restarted the build and... voila!